# How to get rid of mouse hover coordinates using PyPlot?

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

Hej, I'm fairly new to programming. I need to include some PyPlot Figures onto a Tkinter GUI (using Python 2.6). So far so good, made that work, the only annoying thing is that a mouse over effect is automatically applied in the toolbar, which yields exact coordinates of the mouse position. How can I suppress that function? I only found cookbooks on how to format that output, but I want to completely get rid of it.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `'break'` to the application from the listener?

```
def ignore(event):
    return "break"
toolbar.bind("<Enter>", ignore)
```

More details [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the solution for anyone that faces similar problems in the future: you need to edit the function: mouse_move in the module backend_bases of matplotlib. This part is responsible:

if event.inaxes and event.inaxes.get_navigate():

```
        try: s = event.inaxes.format_coord(event.xdata, event.ydata)
        except ValueError: pass
        except OverflowError: pass
        else:
            if len(self.mode):
                self.set_message('%s, %s' % (self.mode, s))
            else:
                self.set_message(s)
    else: self.set_message(self.mode)
```

Just erase or comment it if you want to get rid of the coordinates completely. Might be possible to influence the format there too, didn't try that.

Jakob